# how do i access file system property in node.js

Tags: node.js

const fs=require("fs");
The fs module enables interacting with the file system in a way modeled on standard POSIX functions.

var require: NodeRequire
(id: string) => any
File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module.ts(80001)

Comment: Not sure what the question is. You seem to be using typescript, though. You might consider using Typescript's type definitions for node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node